# If statement for recordStrokes method

Tags: java

The method is to record the number of strokes a player took when completing a hole. The method returns true when strokes are successfully recorded. There are 2 caveats: (1)the hole must be recorded in order and must start with 1. If a hole is received out of order, the score is not recorded and false is returned (2)The hole number must also be valid. You can't record a score for a hole that is less than 1 or greater than the number of holes on the course. Code gives a java.lang.NullPointerException. What does this mean and how do i fix it

Note:  holesPlayed is an instance variable assigned the value of 0

Here is what i have:

```
public boolean recordStrokes(int holeNumber, int strokes) {
    if ((holeNumber >= 1) && (holeNumber <= Course.NUM_OF_HOLES) 
        && (holeNumber == holesPlayed + 1)) {
        scores[holeNumber -1] = strokes;
        holesPlayed = holesPlayed + 1;
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the initial value of holesPlayed when this method in invoked with holeNumber = 1

Comment: I was instructed to assign holesPlayed = 0.

Answer (score 0):

When `holeNumber` 1 is handed in, `holesPlayed` is 0, so this fails: `holeNumber <= this.holesPlayed`.

Comment: I was instructed to assign holesPlayed = 0.  I tried holeNumber <= this.holesPlayed + 1. This caused my test cases to fail.

Comment: This is a homework assignment for my FIRST programming course. My statement seems to satisfy the validity conditions that the program is asking for. Any clues on how I can change it so that it will not not fail?

Comment: I revised my statement to handle the first hole but now I get a java.lang.NullPointerException. What does this mean and how do i fix it